# How to include my javascript file after Telerik includes their javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, telerik

I would like to override Tekerik's javascript function. To do that I want to include a file that contains modified javascript after Telerik's js include.

I include my js files using ClientScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock method. My files are included before Telerik's preventing me from overriding their function.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="myScriptFile.js"></script>
<script src="/atlas/Telerik.Web.UI.WebResource.axd?....></script>
```

How can I include my javascript file after Telerik's?

Comment: Is there a reaspon that you have to include your js files with RegisterClientScriptBlock? Could you not include this one on the page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option that I found is to use [RegisterStartupScript](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.registerstartupscript.aspx) method that

```
 "emits the script just before the closing tag of the Page object's <form runat= server> element."
```

which is after Telerik includes their files.  This doesn't include a js file but at this point I can call a function that overrides Telerik's function.

Comment: This is deprecated. Doesn;t mean you shouldn't use it, but it may cause problems later.

Answer (score -1):

Assuming you want to do this globally, had you considered editing the Telerik source file rather than overriding it?

Comment: Not a good idea - supplied source files should generally be left as they are. Otherwise you end up in a maintenence nightmare.